# How to move product description after product options in Magento2

Tags: product, layout, magento-2.1.2

I want to display product description between size option and qty box.

[image]

I have tried below options :

```
<move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price"/>
<move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.form.options"/>
<move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.options"/>
<move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" after="product_options_wrapper_bottom"/>
<move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" before="product_options_wrapper_bottom"/>
```

But no options worked. 
How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app/design/frontend/{Themepackage}/{themename}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

Added below code

```
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.options.wrapper" after="-"/>
</body>
</page>
```

In file `app/design/frontend/{Themepackage}/{themename}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml`

Added below code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now it is working for both configurable and simple product.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep below xml code into your theme catalog folder,

```
app/design/frontend/{Themepackage}/{themename}/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml
```

**Configurable products,**
`default.xml` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.options.wrapper" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Simple product keep code in below location,

**app/design/frontend/{Themepackage}/{themename}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Above code will not work for simple products.

Comment: i have tested in only config product

Comment: But thanks, code helps me in the over all solution.

Comment: I have added the solution which worked for me.